# How to display the values of an 2D array in a label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a 2D array as follows. I would like to display it using a label on a Windows Form, so it is in a tabular format (rows and columns.) How do I accomplish this?

```
string[,] map = new string[10, 10] 
{ 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }, 
    { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Also can you please specify what exactly you're trying to do? at least for me it's not quite understandable what you're exactly asking and trying to achive.

Comment: Maybe use a grid?

Comment: WinForm labels and tables are completely different; it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Use `monospaced` font like `Consolas` and pad space to left as follow:

```
Label label = new Label();
this.Controls.Add(label);
label.Size = new Size(500, 500); // Enter custom size or use Graphics.MeasureString method to find proper size dynamically
label.AutoSize = false;
label.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        label.Text += map[i, j].PadLeft(5, ' ');
    }
    label.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```